# MVC4 : How to pass nested Ajax request?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4

I make form in a web application , that i filter data according to user selection with ajax and get data with jason all worked well but the problem occur when i want to get nested data
that i get from table BankPlans value and for each bankid i get all required docs from other table i try to get them in one method in jason to select

```
new { Percent = r.percent, Reqdocs = docs });
```

and in the result of ajax loop for each reqDosc to put them in list

i get error when execute method in controller say case 1 = operation and case 2 = operation
then i try another solution to pass them in two methods one to get the percent and id and pass them to the first ajax and for each id get the required docs
the first method execute well but the second get the docs for the last id and put them in all plans when i make abreak point in the next mehod it actually pass in the paramters the three values and only one to execute i think it need async between them but i cannot to do it or if any other solution to solve the problem.

Ajax :

```
                        var addressData = JSON.stringify(jsonData);
                        $.ajax({
                            url: '/Getyourcar/GetPlans',
                            type: "POST",
                            dataType: "json",
                            contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
                            data: addressData,
                            success: function (result) {

                                $("#carousel").empty();

                                for (i = 0; i < result.length; i++) {
                                    $("#carousel").append("<div class='carousel-feature'><div class='content'><h3>الفائدة السنوية</h3><div class='rate'> " + result[i].percent + " </div><div class='feature_cnt'> <ul></ul> </div> <a href='javascript:void(0)' class='check' title=" + result[i].percent + ">اختر</a></div><img class='carousel-image' alt='Image Caption' src='/images/1px.png'></div>");
                                    $('input[name="planid"]').val(result[i].planid);
                                    getDocs();
                                }
                            },
                            error: function (result) {
                            }
                        });


                    }


                    var getDocs = function () {
                        var jsonData = {

                            "Planid": $("#planid").val(),

                        };

                        var addressData = JSON.stringify(jsonData);
                        $.ajax({
                            url: '/Getyourcar/Getdocs',
                            type: "POST",
                            dataType: "json",
                            contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
                            data: addressData,
                            success: function (result) {
                                $("#carousel .feature_cnt ul").empty();

                                for (i = 0; i < result.length; i++) {
                                    $("#carousel .feature_cnt ul").append("<li>" + result[i].plan + " </li>");
                                }

                            },
                            error: function (result) {
                                alert("failed");
                            }
                        });
```

Controller :

```
  public ActionResult GetPlans(string BankName = "", string Period = "", string customergrade = "")
    {
        int bankid = db.Banks.Where(b => b.Name.Contains(BankName) || BankName == "").FirstOrDefault().Id;
        int yearid = db.Yearss.Where(b => b.Name.Contains(Period) || Period == "").FirstOrDefault().Id;

        int cusgradeid = db.CustomerGrades.Where(c => c.Name.Contains(customergrade) || customergrade == "").FirstOrDefault().Id;
        var Bankplanid = db.BankPlanss.Where(b => (b.BankId == bankid) &&
                                                  (b.CustomerGradeId == cusgradeid))
           .Select(r => new { cusgrade = cusgradeid, bankid = r.BankId, percent = r.Percent, planid = r.Id });
        return Json(Bankplanid, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
    }
    public ActionResult Getdocs(int Planid = 0)
    {
        var plans = db.BankPlansReqDocs.Where(b => b.BankPlansId == Planid)
            .Select(r => new { plan = r.RequiredDocs.Name });
        return Json(plans, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
    }
```

When use debugging in VS, case of the Getdocs method called twice in the first time the Planid in the parameter get the value when press F10 the same line called again with the next value and return the Jason of the last value.

Please help ,  Thanks in advance .

Comment: How about some punctuation or periods?

Comment: Im not understanding you about punctuation or periods . You mean to define period for each loop or What ?

Answer (score 0):

The problem solved by pass all docs as a string separated with( , )and all ids in a list .

- In java script split(",") and insert them in specified ul id